# Sound problem Dell XPS 15 9570 with ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, sound, dell, xps

I am having problems with getting the speakers and the headphones working on my new Dell XPS 15. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS, not in dual boot with Windows. I have tried most of the solutions that I found on the Internet but apparently, nothing seems to work, or if it does, it works just partially (only the left speaker or the left headphone) and temporarily. Did someone have the same problem and was able to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a Dell XPS 13, I sporadically have an issue only with headphone, which I can resolve with the command "alsactl restore". You may try. Otherwise, I am surprised of your issues because the Dell's are well supported. I bought mine with Ubuntu 14.04. Do not rule out a hardware issue. I had my motherboard replaced!

Comment: Thanks, however the output I get from "alsactl restore" is `alsactl: load_state:1735: No soundcards found...
`

Comment: Help us help you. "I have tried most of the solutions that I found on the Internet".  Which ones, and what was wrong with each of them.

Comment: @MartinThornton. Yep, sorry. 
So mainly I have tried to:
- uninstall and reinstall alsa-base and pulseaudio
- to reload alsa
- to use alsamixer and pavucontrol
- to activate and deactivate the audio from the bios. 
Nothing has solved my problem. Sometimes when I reboot I get the soundcard working again, but even in that case, even checking with alsamixer and pavucontrol that the speakers are not muted, there is no sound. The same happens with headphones. In that case is even more complex as it is not able to recognize the headphones when I plugged them in right away.

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried again reactivating the audio from the bios and the soundcard is recognized again and the speakers seem to be working, both of them. However, I am sure this is not going to be a stable solution and next time I am going to reboot my laptop things will change. For what concern the headphones, as soon as I try to plug them in they make a continuous and piercing sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever encounter the same problem as mine, I solved:

1. updating my kernel from version 4.4.0.145 to 4.8
2. adding to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

   options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi

Answer (score 0):

You can try to tweak your sound settings with the software Pulsaudio

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already pulseaudio installed and I have already tried to reinstall it  but it wasn't useful

Comment: Since you can't find the sound card I guess it is some device referencing problem, but I can't help much about that. Good luck !