# What are the side effects of upgrading linux kernel from 4.4.0.142 to 4.8 for Ubuntu 16.04? [Sound driver not working]

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, kernel

I have a problem with the sound driver in my Ubuntu 16.04. Most of the time the OS does not recognize the output(it works with headphones).

[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129617/sound-problem-dell-xps-15-9570-with-ubuntu-16-04lts) says updating the kernel from version 4.4.0.145 to 4.8 is a solution. I want to try it but I do not know the side effects. Can anyone tell me what can go wrong if I update my kernel? I have tried uninstalling, installing pulseaudio does not work!

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What type of sound -- over HDMI?  The 4.4.0-142 kernel was the last one before an API change, but another sound problem with that kernel is the i915_component.h extra "int pipe" arg on pin_eld_notify (bug submitted, but ignored).  Edit the fix yoursef and try a recompile. What hardware are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No the system sound, regular laptop speakers. I have a DELL XPS. I really have no idea how to recompile.

Comment: -1 You have trapped yourself in a classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your REAL problem is audio, but you are asking about one possible solution (kernels) instead...so the answers will be about kernels instead of audio. You are likely to find kernel answers unsatisfying. Consider deleting your Question and trying again -- next time ask about the REAL problem.

Comment: Why delete the question? It is a valid question about kernel upgrade. @user535733

Comment: Yes, you are right! Though I wanted to know what impact can kernel change have as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade kernel a better way is to update to the current HWE kernel. That is `4.15`.

The post you mentioned is old, and the `4.8` kernel is obsolete. It used to be a HWE for Ubuntu 16.04.

You can upgrade the kernel by running

```
sudo apt install linux-genric-hwe.16.04
```

It is an officially supported update.

There shouldn't be any side effects unless you installed some 3rd party drivers.

But the 4.4 kernel will stay and if something goes wrong you can always revert back.

Comment: The question was about installing a kernel. I have no idea what was the problem.

Comment: Yes thank you @Pilot6, I upgraded the kernel without any issue.